# como puedo mostrar los datos de un json obtenido desde una api en Angular

Tags: json, angular

estoy haciendo una peticion a una api desde angular, ya la respuesta la tengo y me viene en un json, por lo que logro entender dentro de ese json hay objetos, pero no he logrado entender como puedo acceder a estos valores. lo que tengo hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

el codigo de mi servicio, desde donde hago la petición:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HostlistService {

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS'
    })
  }


  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

  }

  getInmuebles(){
    return this.http.get('URL',this.httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

el codigo de la componente desde donde llamo al servicio:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HostlistService } from '../servicios/hostlist.service';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})

export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  inmuebles = [];

  constructor(private hostlistService: HostlistService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inmuebles=this.hostlistService.getInmuebles();

  }
}
```

Basicamente lo que quiero es, desde el componente Slider mandar a imprimir los datos del .json en el .html.

como puedo hacerlo? estoy comenzando en angular y antes de pasar por acá busque informacion pero no he logrado aplicarla a lo que quiero. Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar.

aqui dejo la respuesta por consola que es lo que he podido mostrar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente recibes un objeto json que equivale a un arreglo, este array lo puedes recorrer en tu html con la directiva `*ngFor`:

Servicio

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ServiceName {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getInmuebles(){
    return this.http.get<any>('url');
  }
}
```

Componente

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServiceName } from '../PathService';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ccc',
  templateUrl: './ccc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ccc.component.css']
})

export class cccComponent implements OnInit {
  inmu = [];
  constructor(
    private data: ServiceName,
  ) { }

  getInmu(){
   this.data.getInmuebles().subscribe((response)=> {
   this.inmu = response["data"];
   });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getInmu();
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of inmu">
    {{item.nomb_prod_c}}
</div>
```

Resultado

[image: LISTA DE INMUEBLES]

Comment: Hola, gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder. eso no iria en el componente en vez de colocarlo en el mismo servicio ? es una duda que tengo. Te pregunto porque lo hice como la persona que respondio mas abajo, es decir lo coloque en el componente y me muestra ciertos errores que puedes verlos en mi comentario.

Comment: si, me equivoque, es en el componente

Comment: ok, pero lo coloque y me muestra estos errores, : ERROR in src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(13,3): error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected. src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(16,23): error TS1005: ',' expected. src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(16,38): error TS1005: ',' expected. src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(16,57): error TS1005: ';' expected. src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(18,14): error TS1005: ';' expected. src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(22,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: podrás poner el codigo de tu servicio y componente completos..

Comment: listo, ya edite mi pregunta.

Comment: en tu servicio podrias probar con:
 'const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })'
};

Comment: por que modificar las cabeceras que al parecer estan bien, el error que me esta mostrando actualmente es este: ERROR in src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(19,5): error TS2740: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more. Si quito la declaracion de la variable inmueble el error desaparece.

Comment: Teneis razon, de hecho lo puedes hacer sin los 'headers' edite mi respuesta y con ese codigo ya me muestra los datos de tu API

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94312/discussion-between-prospero-aguilar-and-julianprog).

Answer (score 0):

el metodo getInmuebles(), te devuelve los datos que necesitas.

```
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {

let data = [];

constructor(private hostlistService: HostlistService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     data = this.hostlistService.getInmuebles();

  }
}
```

esa variable let data deberia de tener toda los datos que te retorna el metodo, a partir de ahi puedes jugar con el html.

Con un ng-for en el html component, puede hacer uso de la variable data.

Comment: amigo mo difique el codigo tal cual como lo escribiste y muestra esto:    ERROR in src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(13,3): error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(16,23): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(16,38): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(16,57): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(18,14): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/app/slider/slider.component.ts(22,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

Answer (score 0):

puedes tratar de hacer lo siguiente , esto lo debes de hacer en tu componente

```
Metodo() {
    this.hostlistService.getInmuebles().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.variable = result;
      },
      error => {
        const errorMessage = <any>error;
        console.error(errorMessage);
      }
    );
  }
```

Debes declarar este metodo en el OnInit para que pueda correr y no olvides declarar la variable de esta forma

```
public variable : any;
```

Pinta la respuesta en un cosole log para que puedas ver la información y la estructura.

En el `html` puedes mostrarlo con un `ngFor`

Comment: debo quitar el subscribe que tengo en el servicio? sinceramente no entiendo muy bien la teoria de los observables y subscribe, estoy leyendo una documento sobre eso.

Comment: Normal mente puedes hacer esto en el servicio --- 

MetodoServicio() {
        this.url = this.envirment.Url + '/urldelapi' ;
        return this._http.get(this.url).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
    }

Comment: no me funciona. estoy intentando hacerlo como muestran en la documentacion oficial de angular y tampoco funciona, no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Muéstrame el error que aparece muéstrame el código donde conviertes el objeto o el json